# Remove not used resourses from app before loading to google play

Tags: android, google-play

How to Remove not used resourses from app?
For minimize app size.
I saw the article but i can not find it (

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio, Use Refactor in menu

> Refactor-> Remove Unused Resources

[image]